# can we get some mobile version of the related questions box / panel that I find on SE on my laptop web browser?

Tags: feature-request

I spend most of my time on my mobile and do most of my SE stuff on it. I chat, I ask, I comment -- all of it on my mobile. But when I try to decide whether to ask or answer a question, I unfortunately don't have any way on my mobile to see if there are related questions already on SE. Sure I can google, but this is unreasonable for a variety of reasons (e.g. if I've typed something in an answer box in chrome and change to a tab google, what I typed often gets deleted when I return because the tab refreshes).

so it would really be convenient if I could have access to the related question information on my mobile. sure it might have to be fitted for mobile format but I think that would be really helpful. Then if a question exists with an answer, I don't have to ask it. I also can avoid answering one if I knew the question already had an answer.

Comment: Probably belongs on the mother meta. But *I'm* on my mobile now and it's just toon inconvenient to hunt for an existing instance.

Comment: Just to be clear, is this about the mobile site, or about one of the dedicated apps (iOS or Android)?

Comment: Neither app or mobile website has it. I probably could deal with it if one of them had it but as far as I have seen no medium has that feature besides the full out web browser of my laptop.

Comment: Have you tried just setting your phone to request the desktop version of the site rather than the mobile? I know on Android/Chrome browser this is simple, it's just a checkbox on the menu. That's how I use the site on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the mobile site (via the browser), [the "official" answer is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240733/why-arent-related-questions-shown-on-the-mobile-interface),

> I don't really see us adding lists of questions to the mobile web views at this point since they'd come off largely too cluttered, and the views aren't designed to fully mimic the desktop version in the first place.

Though, in the comments, it is suggested that there *could* be a link for it, but no such designs have come through (otherwise you'd not be asking ;) ).

As to the app interface, [this one was asked and the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246153/related-questions-when-asking) (via comments) is

> It doesn't exist today but it's a good idea. I don't think the API has an endpoint for it yet

So basically it seems you are out of luck at the moment.

Comment: Annoying / too bad. thx for answering.